# A question on linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a problem I’ve been working on as part of my studies for an upcoming comprehensive exam:

> Let $F$ be a field, let $V\in F$-$\mathrm{Mod}$ be a finite-dimensional left $F$-vector space, and let $T\in\mathrm{End}_{F}\left(V\right)$ be an $F$-linear operator.
>
> (a)  Suppose that $\mathrm{rk}(T)=\mathrm{rk}\left(T^2\right)$.  Prove that $\mathrm{ker}(T)\cap T[V]=\left\{0_V\right\}$, and deduce from this that $V=\mathrm{ker}(T)\oplus T[V]$.
>
> (b) Prove that $V=\mathrm{ker}\left(T^k\right)\oplus T^{k}[V]$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

I’ve solved part (a); if $v\in\mathrm{ker}(T)\cap T[V]$, then $v=T(w)$ for some $w\in V$ and $T(v)=0_V$, so $w\in\mathrm{ker}\left(T^2\right)$.  By assumption, $\mathrm{rk}(T)=\mathrm{rk}\left(T^2\right)$.  By the Dimension Theorem, $\dim(V)=\mathrm{rk}(T)+\dim\left(\mathrm{ker}(T)\right)=\mathrm{rk}\left(T^2\right)+\dim\left(\mathrm{ker}\left(T^2\right)\right)$, so $\dim\left(\mathrm{ker}(T)\right)=\dim\left(\mathrm{ker}\left(T^2\right)\right)$.  Since, clearly, $\mathrm{ker}\left(T^2\right)\supseteq\mathrm{ker}(T)$ (as $T$ is $F$-linear), we have that $\mathrm{ker}(T)=\mathrm{ker}\left(T^2\right)$ (as $V$ is finite-dimensional).  Hence $v=0_V$.  The Dimension Theorem then allows us to conclude that $V=\mathrm{ker}(T)\oplus T[V]$.

A solution to part (b) has as yet eluded me.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I see how a solution might go, but I need an answer to the following question:  is an $F$-space a Noetherian module?  If so, I think I have a solution.

Comment: An $F$-vector space is Noetherian iff it is finite dimensional. If $V$ is not f.d., then we contruct an ascending chain in the obvious way, and if it is f.d., then all chains halt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: Notice that the ranks of $T^k$ form a decreasing integer sequence bounded below by 0. Hence eventually they become constant, and thus the ranks of $T^n$ and $T^{?}$ for all $?>n$ must be the same. What choice of $?$ allows you to use a result you already know?